# creating graphs in wolfram alpha

Tags: calculus, graphing-functions

I am trying to plot the function $$\max(x-40,0)$$ in Wolfram|Alpha, but I can't figure out how.

What Wolfram|Alpha query URL should I use to produce this graph? Or, what similar online program could I use to produce this graph?

Answer (score 2):

Try out [Desmos](https://www.desmos.com/calculator).

Typing $y=\max \left(x-40,0\right)$ works perfectly.

Here's a [link](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/kb0dxmvo44) to this graph:
[image: Rendered graph]

Comment: OK, but how to do the same thing in Excel?

Comment: And, how to bring this into a format so I can copy and paste this graph in a format like excel

Comment: thanks for the help!

Comment: Excel is not a graphing program. You could create a data table and use a scatter plot, if you want. Or, you could save [this image](https://s3.amazonaws.com/grapher/exports/kb0dxmvo44.png) and import it as a picture.

Answer (score 0):

Wolfram|Alpha works for me if you specify the bounds for $x$:

» [plot max(x - 40, 0) from x = -20 to 60](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+max%28x-40%2C+0%29+from+x%3D-20+to+60)